# System boot results in `BOOTMGR missing`, `missing operating system`, `no bootable devices`

Tags: boot, upgrade

During an upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04 my computer suddenly froze. I restarted the computer and now it will not boot. I have seen various messages such as `BOOTMGR missing`, `missing operating system`, `no bootable devices`.

I tried using boot repair but it did not help.

Comment: Possibly useful, if you need to recover data and reinstall, as Xernicus recommends: http://askubuntu.com/q/126724

Answer (score 2):

Are you dual booting Windows and Linux? From what I see, Linux does not see a valid boot loader, and BOOTMGR sounds awfully Windows Vista/7 like. And I know for a fact that Linux uses no such file. It also looks like your partition table may be damaged. I wouldn't be surprised if having two bootloaders on your hard drive is part of the issue (You have one on the MBR, and on Partition 2).

At this point, I'd say your best bet would be to copy all of your files on your home partition (or home folder) onto an external hard drive or flash disk and reinstall Linux. If you use Windows, be sure to get it in a working state using startup repair, or the recovery console before installing Linux, otherwise you won't be able to boot into Ubuntu. I'm not going to lie when I say you may need to reformat the disk as well.

I'm sorry that this is the case, and I hope that you're able to recover all of your documents.

Cheers!
Camden Stensland, Fedora Quality Assurance Officer

Comment: How do I go about copying all of the files? I am running windows 7 on my other laptop here and its not reading the sata drive which has ubuntu installed.

Comment: no not dual booting. I was running windows 7 on it previously though. Maybe it didnt completely wipe off windows when I installed ubuntu 11.1o. I have only been using linux for a few months so I dont know much. I have been a windows user my whole life and I am trying to switch over to linux.